# Javascript form validation not being called

Tags: javascript

When I click on the submit button, it just loads the next page instead of running the javascript code.

This is my javascript code:

```
function Validate(thisForm)
    {
        alert("started");
        var username22 = document.thisForm.getElementById('username');
        var password22 = document.thisForm.getElementById('password');
        var password222 = document.thisForm.getElementById('password2');
        var email22 = document.thisForm.getElementById('email');
        var email222 = document.thisForm.getElementById('email2');
        var legalcheck22 = document.thisForm.getElementById('legal');
        alert("started 2");
        if(username22.value == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter a username.");
            focus.username22;
            return false;
        }
        alert("started 3");
        if(password22.value.length < 5)
        {
            alert("Password needs to be at least 5 characters long.");
            focus.password22;
            return false;
        }
        alert("started 4");
        if(password22.value != password2.value)
        {
            alert("Passwords don't match.");
            focus.password22;
            return false;
        }
        alert("started 5");
        if(email22.value == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter an email.");
            focus.email22;
            return false;
        }
        alert("started 6");
        if(email222.value == "")
        {
            alert("Please confirm your email.");
            focus.email222;
            return false;
        }
        alert("started 7");
        if(email22.value != email222.value)
        {
            alert("Emails don't match.");
            focus.email22;
            return false;
        }
        if(legalcheck22.checked == false)
        {
            alert("You need to agree to our Terms and Conditions.");
            focus.legalcheck22;
            return false;
        }
        alert("pass");
        return true;
    }
```

And this is my form

```
<div class="formLayout">
        <form id="registerForm" name="registerForm" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate(registerForm)" action="register.php" >
          <h3 class="centeredText">Register Account</h3>
          <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input name="username" id="username" />
            <br />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
            <br />
            <label>Confirm Passwrd</label>
            <input name="password2" type="password" id="password2" />
            <br />
            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" />
            <br />
            <label>Confirm Email</label>
            <input name="email2" id="email2" />
            <br />
            <label>Captcha</label>
            <input id="captcha" />
          </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
          <div id="centerButtons">
            <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
            <input type="reset" name="register2" id="register2" value="Reset" />
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </div> 
          <!-- end of centerButtons-->
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="legal" id="legal" />
            <label for="legal">I agree to the <a href="terms.html">Terms and Conditions</a>.</label>
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
    </div> 
    <!-- end of formLayout div-->
```

I am not sure why the page keeps loading when javascript code is started. It manages to show the first alert ("started") and then the page reloads. Can you please help me out? Thanks

Comment: You know what's funny, you wrote all this(which I doubt it) and you didn't even test it if it works or not?!

Comment: I wrote it from scratch and how come I haven't tested it? I am obviously posting here because it doesn't works.

Comment: Your `<label>` elements don't have `for` attributes, nor do they contain `<input>`s, that renders them worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` is a property of the `document` object, not of all `Element` objects.

`var username22 = document.thisForm.getElementById('username');` will throw an exception, killing the JS, and allowing form submission to continue as normal.

Comment: Thank you, you got me in the right direction. It works now :)